# Sparodic OutOfBounds issue with Netty 4.01 CR6

Tags: netty, indexoutofboundsexception, decoder

I am having a problem with a custom decoder that I developed and am not sure what I am doing wrong.

The message format that we receive contains a HEADER, BODY and TRAILER. The header is 1 byte and is an STX (0x02) The body is variable length The trailer is 2 bytes which contain an ETX(0x03) followed by an LRC.

So a typical message might look like:

```
STX   BODY   ETX  LRC
02  37000000 06   18
```

The output of the Decoder should be the message without the STX control byte. So the message being sent on is:

```
BODY     ETX  LRC
37000000 06   18
```

We extended the DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder and defined the ETX as the delimiter. The decoder intent is to read the next byte, add it to the buffer and then send it on, that way we are sending a complete message.  Our decode method looks like this:

```
protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buffer) throws Exception {
    Object frame = super.decode(ctx, buffer);

    if (frame == null) {
        return null;
    }
    ByteBuf msg = null;

    if (frame instanceof ByteBuf) {
        msg = Unpooled.copiedBuffer((ByteBuf) frame);
        msg.writeByte(buffer.readByte());
        ((ByteBuf) frame).release();
    }

    while (msg.getByte(0) != STX) {
        msg.readByte();
        msg = msg.discardReadBytes();
    }

    return msg;
}
```

Everything works as expected, except that periodically we receive the following exception.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(225) + length(1) exceeds writerIndex(225): UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 225, widx: 225, cap: 256)
```

We are using Netty 4.01 CR6 and it is a sporadic issue.  What I am not sure of, is this something that I am not doing correctly, or is it an issue that is within Netty.  Since I am pretty new to Netty I suspect that it is something I am doing, but I am not sure.

I am hoping that someone can help me resolve this.  I am more then happy to post anymore information to get this resolved, just ask.

Appreciate any and all help I can get on this one.

- Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception means that you are trying to read a byte from the bytebuf that it doesn't contain, because you reached the end of it.

Either the client has send invalid data, or not all packets in your protocol have the `STX` in the message.

A other mistake that is commonly made when decoding a already existing protocol is that the byte sequence you are using as a delimiter is used inside the packets itself, and that you are expected to read the packets byte by byte.

If you want to see the packets flowing to your decoder, you can add a `LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO)` to the pipeline, just before your decoder is ran, so it will print out the raw bytes as a hex, so you can check if it actually contains the byte sequences needed.

*Sidenote*: You are never releasing the bytebuf stored in `msg`. This will create memory leaks and will eventually lead to a OOM, make sure to call release in a try-finally block so its always called